# absolute div inside fieldset with legend

Tags: html, css, position

Why does the `.discount-edg` container not align to the top right corner of my `fieldset`? If I remove the `<legend>`, it works. And why do Chrome and Firefox display different?

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #E67E22;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: .625rem;
  position: relative;
}
fieldset legend {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
fieldset .discount-edg {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 50px 50px 0;
  border-color: transparent #ff0000 transparent transparent;
}
fieldset .discount-edg .value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 700;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Testlegend with long text that wraps</legend>
  <div class="discount-edg"><div class="value">- 50%</div></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: fieldset .discount-edg {top: -1em} because the legend element is present and pushes it down

Comment: @VXp That seems to fix the issue in Firefox, but not in Chrome..

Comment: For Chrome it's the opposite: positive 1em

Comment: The legend container is just a block element. Why does it affect an absolute positioned element at all?

Comment: Because it affects where the top border of the fiedset goes - with legends and fieldsets, the fieldset top border always goes through the middle of the legend.  If it's not a form, just use divs.  I would say using it for grouping none form elements is semantically incorrect anyway

Comment: That happens because the fieldset has a border of 1 px so to align you have to add `right: -1px` in .discount-edg class

Comment: It affects the parents height since its position isn't changed and the "discount" is positioned relative to it. Give the legend position: absolute to see the non-affecting difference.

Comment: [More information about my comment](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#rendered-legend) *A fieldset element’s rendered legend... then the legend is expected to be rendered aligned in the inline direction over the border edge..*

Comment: This thread explains the difference between ff and chrome - apparently webkit displays  it wrong: https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/168

Comment: Thank you guys for your explanation. I'll use a div instead of legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discount edge does align with the top of the fieldset, it's just that the top border of a fieldset will always run through the middle of a legend.

[From w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#rendered-legend):

> A fieldset element’s rendered legend, if any, is expected to be rendered over the block-start border edge of the fieldset element as a block box (overriding any explicit display value). In the absence of an explicit inline size, the box should shrink-wrap. If the legend element in question has an align attribute, and its value is an ASCII case-insensitive match for one of the strings in the first column of the following table, then the legend is expected to be rendered aligned in the inline direction over the border edge in the position given in the corresponding cell on the same row in the second column.

The difference between firefox and chrome is [caused by a bug in the way webkit handles collapsed margins for fieldsets](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=758346)

I would change to use divs as using fieldsets for anything other than group form controls  is semantically incorrect anyway.

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
}

.fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #E67E22;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: .625rem;
  position: relative;
}
.fieldset .legend {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0px 60px 0 10px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  position:absolute;
  background:white;
  top:0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.fieldset .discount-edg {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 50px 50px 0;
  border-color: transparent #ff0000 transparent transparent;
}
.fieldset .discount-edg .value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 700;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldset">
  <div class="legend">Test legend with long text that wraps</div>
  <div class="discount-edg"><div class="value">- 50%</div></div>
</div><br><br>
<div class="fieldset">
  <div class="legend">One line</div>
  <div class="discount-edg"><div class="value">- 50%</div></div>
</div>
```